# Selecting a variable to plot in a bar chart with Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the following dataset:

[image]

```
data <- structure(list(country = c("Andorra", "Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece"), x48 = c(811.73, 710.0385, 765.8359, 961.434, 701.9176, 716.7308, 701.6187, 468.1942), x49 = c(655.2433, 607.8058, 628.3675, 692.426, 575.4287, 587.7711, 544.2052, 370.2103), x54 = c(2801.597, 2224.757, 2320.216, 3130.023, 2582.625, 2399.011, 2621.368, 804.5603)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to plot a double bar chart that shows, for each country in the x-axis, a bar with the values of 'x54' and a bar for either 'x48' or 'x49' like so:

[image]

With the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.csv("data/salario-apartamento-europa-occidental-pequeño.csv")

  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Triple Bar Chart"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("x1", "Type of house:", choices = names(df)[-1], selected = names(df)[1]),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  )
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(-country)
      ggplot(data = df_long %>% 
               filter(name %in% c("x49", "x54")),  
             aes(x = country, y = value, fill = factor(name))) +
        geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("#58C114", "#DA560A")) +
        theme_light()  +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
        scale_color_manual(name = "Metric", labels = c("1 room in the center", "Average Monthly Salary")) + 
        labs(fill =" Metric", x= "Country", y= "USD")
    })
  }

# run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I can do it as you can see, but you'll realize that, instead of filtering by 'x54' and the input variable "x1", I'm filtering by 'x49' thus, instead of being reactive, for me to compare 'x54' and 'x48', I have to change it manually in the code.

I would like to have something similar to this:

```
filter(name %in% c(input$x1, "x54"))
```

But unfortunatelly, this doesn't work and it only plots 'x54'.

Also, how would I update the labels accordingly? (Now they stay like 'x49' and 'x54' as you can see in the picture)

It should be like so:

***For 'x54':*** Average Monthly Salary

***For 'x48':*** 1 room in the center

***And for 'x49':*** 1 room outside the center

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `selectInput`, the object used is `data` and not `df`

```
selectInput("x1", "Type of house:", choices = names(df)[-1], 
        selected = names(df)[1]),
      ),
...
```

where

```
df <- read.csv("data/salario-apartamento-europa-occidental-pequeño.csv")
```

-full code

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Andorra", "Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece"), x48 = c(811.73, 710.0385, 765.8359, 961.434, 701.9176, 716.7308, 701.6187, 468.1942), x49 = c(655.2433, 607.8058, 628.3675, 692.426, 575.4287, 587.7711, 544.2052, 370.2103), x54 = c(2801.597, 2224.757, 2320.216, 3130.023, 2582.625, 2399.011, 2621.368, 804.5603)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Triple Bar Chart"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x1", "Type of house:", choices = names(df)[-1], selected = names(df)[1]),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$x1)
    df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(-country)
    
    
    ggplot(data = df_long %>% 
             filter(name %in% c(input$x1, "x54")),  
           aes(x = country, y = value, fill = factor(name))) +
      geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#58C114", "#DA560A"), 
               labels= setNames( c("1 room in the center", "Average Monthly Salary"), c("x48", "x49"))) +
      theme_light()  +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
       labs(fill =" Metric", x= "Country", y= "USD")
  })
}

# run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I actually notice that issue just after posting the question and I didn't realize that that was  the problem hahahaha thank you!

Comment: Any ideas on why the labels don't update though?

Comment: @walter it is updating fine for me when I change the Type of house to a different value

Comment: @walter Are you talking about the legend labels?  It is updating for me

Comment: Yes, the legends, it updates from 'x48' to 'x49' but I would like to have them like I explained in the last section of the question

Comment: @walter I noticed that you have used `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual`.  We could modify the `scale_fill_manual` to include a named vector of labels and remove the scale_color_manual.  Please find the update

Answer (score 3):

Your `input` needs to be a reactive. https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html

Your server would need to look more like this.

```
server = function(input, output) {
  
  yourinput <- reactive({
    input$x1
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(-country)
    ggplot(data = df_long %>% 
             filter(name %in% c(yourinput(), "x54")),  
           aes(x = country, y = value, fill = factor(name))) +
      geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#58C114", "#DA560A")) +
      theme_light()  +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
      scale_color_manual(name = "Metric", labels = c("1 room in the center", "Average Monthly Salary")) + 
      labs(fill =" Metric", x= "Country", y= "USD")
  })
}
```

Comment: Contrary to my first thought, akrun has a solution without a reactive variable.